# Nodejs parsing min and max values returning wrong values

Tags: node.js, csv

I'm using [csv-parser](http://npmjs.org/csv-parser) to parse a csv file I have. Then as it's parsing each line, I'm checking each value in the line to get the min and max.

My issue is that my max keeps coming out as 99 in the COL and ROW columns. when their maxs are around 200 for row and 300 for col. I'm not sure whats happening there, as far as I know my method should work.

Here is my relevant code:

```
var mins = {}
var maxs = {}
function loadCSV(finishedCallback) {
    console.log("Loading csv...");
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/data.csv')
    .pipe(stream)
    .on('data', function (data) {
        for (var k in data) {
              if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                  if (mins[k] == undefined)
                      mins[k] = data[k];
                  if (maxs[k] == undefined)
                      maxs[k] = data[k];

                  if (mins[k] > data[k])
                      mins[k] = data[k];
                  if (maxs[k] < data[k])
                      maxs[k] = data[k];

              }
          }
      }).on('finish', function () {
          console.log("Finished reading csv!")
          finishedCallback();
          console.log("Maxs: " + JSON.stringify(maxs));
          console.log("Mins: " + JSON.stringify(mins));
          return true
      })
}
```

And here are the first few lines of my CSV: (I'm aware of the duplicate x and y fields, I don't end up using then)

```
X,Y,X,Y,ROW,COL,EMH,EMV,ASP,DEM,SLOPE
495118.8125,4469900.5,495118.80000,4469901.00000,0,79,15.56310,8.11320,285.65760,318.85077,0.12900
495120.8125,4469900.5,495120.80000,4469901.00000,0,80,15.64225,8.12110,286.47190,318.87570,0.13107
495122.8125,4469900.5,495122.80000,4469901.00000,0,81,15.76020,8.10590,287.70340,318.91686,0.13890
```

I have a felling I'm probably being stupid and missing something obvious :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing strings instead of numbers:

```
$ node
> '99' > '300'
true
```

So before doing any comparisons, convert `data[k]` to a number first:

```
var value = Number(data[k]);
```

Comment: That's the third time I've done that, assuming an library used numbers instead of string. I really need to start checking that :P